# ReactJS : onClick in sub-component does not trigger

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a sub-component in JSX which is a list of items with an onClick event and an event handler. The event handler is never called. Please help me figure out what i am doing wrong.

- The React Chrome developer tools extension shows an "onClick" event handler being created for each "li"
- The context (this) is the "Constructor" object which has the "handleClick" function as a property.

EDIT:
Thanks to @FakeRainBrigand, i found out the problem was elsewhere.
I figured out that when I hide/show the sub-component using an event handler in the parent component, it stops triggering the onClick event handler, since the parent's hide operation triggers. [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/vinepese/1/edit)

The JSX code.

```
var FilterList = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function(e){
        console.log(e);

    },
    render: function(){
        var ListItems = this.props.data.map(function(item){
            return (
                <li key={item.id} className="filter-item" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    <span key={'img'+item.id} className={item.imgClass}></span>
                    <span key={'text'+item.id} className="item-text">{item.name}</span>
                </li>
            )

        }, this);
        return (
            <div className="filter-list">
                    <ul>
                        {ListItems}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            );
    }
});
```

The generated JS code:

```
var FilterList = React.createClass({displayName: 'FilterList',
    handleClick: function(e){
        console.log(e);


    },
    render: function(){
        var ListItems = this.props.data.map(function(item){
            return (
                React.DOM.li( {key:item.id, className:"filter-item", onClick:this.handleClick}, 
                    React.DOM.span( {key:'img'+item.id, className:item.imgClass}),
                    React.DOM.span( {key:'text'+item.id, className:"item-text"}, item.name)
                )
            )

        }, this);
        return (
            React.DOM.div( {className:"filter-list"}, 
                    React.DOM.ul(null, 
                        ListItems
                    )
                )
            );
    }
});
```

Comment: Your problem is elsewhere.  [This code works](http://jsbin.com/zotoweqo/2/edit?js,output)

Comment: Thanks for the jsbin sample. I can see that is working, and I am officially lost. The complete code is the same as the jsbin, but I'm getting the `data` from the server using `ComponentWillMount`. Any ideas about where to look? I can rewrite parts of the code. Any lead is fine, I've been stuck on this for the past day.

Comment: Is that the capitalization you used, "ComponentWillMount"? The function begins with a lowercase "c": `componentWillMount`.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you add a self = this; and change the this.handleClick to self.handleClick?

render: function() {

```
    self = this;
    var ListItems = this.props.data.map(function(item){

        return (
            <li key={item.id} className="filter-item" onClick={self.handleClick}>
                <span key={'img'+item.id} className={item.imgClass}></span>
                <span key={'text'+item.id} className="item-text">{item.name}</span>
            </li>
        )

    }, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to make your server/ajax call in componentDidMount, not componentWillMount. You can check out why in the documentation here [React Component Lifecycle](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount)

Answer (score 0):

maybe use callback function. use callback on `onclick` like this:

```
var FilterList = React.createClass({
handleClick: function(e){
    console.log(e);

},
render: function(){
    var ListItems = this.props.data.map(function(item){
        return (
            <li key={item.id} className="filter-item" onClick={() => this.handleClick}>
                <span key={'img'+item.id} className={item.imgClass}></span>
                <span key={'text'+item.id} className="item-text">{item.name}</span>
            </li>
        )

    }, this);
    return (
        <div className="filter-list">
                <ul>
                    {ListItems}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
}
});
```